# How to use Slater Type Orbitals as a basis functions in matrix method correctly?

Tags: integration, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, change-of-basis, eigenfunctions

This question is a continuation of my previous series of questions about basis functions.

I would like to find the minimum energy of Coulomb potential motion using matrix method.

$H=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta-\frac{1}{r}$

I have chosen Slater Type Orbitals as a basis functions $R(r)=Nr^{n-1}e^{-r}$ ,$ \quad n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...$ (formula 11.2.2 from here https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Pacific_Union_College/Quantum_Chemistry/11%3A_Computational_Quantum_Chemistry/11.02%3A_Gaussian_Basis_Sets )

The answer is known from the general theory ($E_{min} = -0.5$)

My Wolfram Mathematica code give the next values:

$E_{min} = -0.874888131489401$ - 5 basis functions 
$E_{min} = -1.7871262624523565$ - 10 basis functions 
$E_{min} = -2.407853444926228$ - 15 basis functions 
$E_{min} = -2.858626490878647$ - 20 basis functions

The increase in basis functions number gives increase in the absolute value of the energy and it is so far from -0.5. But with increase of the basis functions number, the energy value should get closer to the correct value. What have I done wrong?

The code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
nmax = 5;
Psi1[r_, n_] := r^(n - 1) Exp[-1*r^2];
NN[n_] := 
  1/Sqrt[Integrate[Psi1[r, n]*Psi1[r, n]*r^2, {r, 0, Infinity}]];
Psi[r_, n_] := NN[n]*r^(n - 1) Exp[-1*r^2];
(*kinetic energy*)
Kk[r_, n1_, n2_] := 
  FullSimplify[
   Psi[r, n2]*
    Laplacian[Psi[r, n1], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"]];
Kx[n1_, n2_] := -0.5*Integrate[Kk[r, n1, n2]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
KK = Table[Kx[n1, n2], {n1, 1, nmax}, {n2, 1, nmax}];

(*potential energy*)
VP1[r_] := -1/r;
Px1[n1_, n2_] := 
  Integrate[Psi[r, n2]*VP1[r]*Psi[r, n1]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
PP = Table[Px1[n1, n2], {n1, 1, nmax}, {n2, 1, nmax}];
Coulomb = Min[Eigenvalues[KK + PP]]

Out[2009]= -0.874888
```

Comment: You should say that it is a Mathematica code.

Comment: I don't know Mathematica well enough, so just some observations: In the code you have $r^{n-1}e^{-r^2}$ instead of $r^{n-1}e^{-r}$. That doesn't explain your trouble - you should always find $E_{min}(N)\geq -1/2$. On top of that, if you used the basis  $r^{n-1}e^{-r}$, you should get $E_{min}(N) = -1/2$ for all $N$'s, as $e^{-r}$ is the true eigenfunction with the lowest eigenvalue $-1/2$.

Comment: @user8268, thanks for the comment!

Comment: @user8268, what programming language is better to use for the Mathematics part of StackExchange?

Comment: I think that Mathematica is a good choice for the typical audience here (your code is perfectly readable even for me, but spotting bugs is beyond my skills)

Comment: [Cross-posted to mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/281856/) and comprehensively answered there. Please don't do that, especially not without linking the questions to each other and explaining your reason for cross-posting. It wastes everyone's time. I'd already spent some time working on an answer, and I would have wasted more time if the cross-post hadn't showed up by pure chance in the sidebar on another question.